# sharepoint 2013 - How to create a news page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, are there any OOTB tools that will allow me to do a news posting?  For example, display 5 to 10 postings on a single page, and each item has an expiration date.  Anyway to do this without turning on mysites or additional software applications?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this. From my experience the simplest and flexible approach is to make use of Content Search WebPart

1. Create a custom list where you want to manage the News Source; Or better create a new content type (You can add RichText fields to capture the News Description, you can have a news title, you can have an image etc.)
2. Once this is completed, create a page where you want to display the data
3. Now edit the page and add a Content Search webpart
4. Change the webpart query to get all items have the Content Type you created in #1 also add extra filter to remove expired items
5. You can set the Number of items = 5 or 10
6. Choose Display Template of your choice
7. Save and exit

Comment: this sounds exciting, let me try to go in and follow these steps in my system....

Comment: Sadly CSWP is an enterprise only feature =[

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer posted here, you could use the out of the box Annoncements app which is a list pre-configured for news and announcements.

If you want to have news on pages then it makes sense to use a custom list or create pages in the Pages/Site Pages library and use Content Search Webpart to display them on the page you want.